# Laravel 9 - Cannot get datas from foreign id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm creating a **shop**, with **products** and **shopping cart**.

The products' table name on PHPMyAdmin is called "**boutiques**".
The Shopping Cart's table name on PHPMyAdmin is called "**paniers**".
Here are they :

**BOUTIQUES TABLE :**

[image]

**PANIERS TABLE :**

[image]

As you can see on the "paniers" table, I get **foreign ids** back from "**boutiques**" table, especially idproduit (id from "boutiques" table).
I'm trying to get back information like "nom", "description" etc from "boutiques" table **according to the idpanier from "paniers" table**.

I tried this request :

```
$produits = Boutique::where('idproduit', '=', 'idpanier')->get(['idproduit', 'nom','description', 'prix', 'img']);
        dd($produits);
```

But it's **empty**... where did I go wrong ? *Thanks for your help* !

**MODEL PANIER** :

```
class Panier extends Model
{
    protected $fillable  = [
        "idpanier",
        "iduser",
        "idproduit",
        "quantité",

    ];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

**MODEL BOUTIQUE** :

```
class Boutique extends Model
{

    protected $fillable  = [
        "iduser",
        "idproduit",
        "nom",
        "description",
        "prix",
        "img",
        "quantité",
    ];
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: I think this `'idpanier'` needs to be a value that exists in that column and not just a string with the name in, so `where('idproduit', '=', '1')` for example or `where('idproduit', '=', $value_of_one_you_have_stored_somewhere)`

Comment: Could probably because you're referencing the query to `boutique` model but the `'idpanier'` is an attribute of `paniers` model. `'panier.idpanier'` to reference the attribute to the correct model.

Comment: According to your advices I tried this request : $paniers = Boutique::join('paniers', 'paniers.iduser', '=', 'paniers.idpanier')->where('paniers.iduser', '=', $sessionID)->get();

But I get all the products from "boutiques" table, not the products in the shopping cart according to the iduser session :/

Comment: I have to write "paniers.idpanier" on Boutique model ?